# Why Can't I get Total Number of Items and Bind it to ngModel?

Tags: angular, ionic4

The API returns the data like so:

```
{
    "data": {
        "collections": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Collection One",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "collection_id": 1,
                        "name": "Item One",
                        "myitems": [
                            {
                                "id": 21,
                                "quantity": 18
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "collection_id": 1,
                        "name": "Item Two",
                        "myitems": [
                            {
                                "id": 22,
                                "quantity": 3
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "collection_id": 1,
                        "name": "Item Three",
                        "myitems": []
                    },
            }
    }
}
```

I'm looping through the array and printing out the collection names, then looping through and printing out the collection items. I'm also printing the total number of items in the Collection.

In this example there are 3 items in the collection. A user can collect each item multiple times, so as we can see this user has collected `Item 1` 18 times, `Item 2` 3 times, and `Item 3` 0 times.

What I'm trying to do is display the number of items the user has collected next to the total number of items in the Collection. So in this instance the user has collected 2 items out of 3. I don't care about the quantity of items they collected, I only care that the user has collected an item. So the text would be `Collection One: 2 of 3`

This is what it looks like in Ionic:

```html
<span class="heading" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="collectionId[collection.id]"></span> of {{ collection.items.length || '0' }}
```

Here's where I'm stuck. I can get the collection total (3); I'm doing it in the HTML, but I CAN'T get the item count. Everything I'm trying just doesn't work.

```js
getData() {
    return this.storage.get('token').then(res => {
        if (res) {
            this.http.get('http://api.example.com/collections)
                .subscribe((result: any) => {
                    for (const collection of result.data.collections) {
                        let quantity = [];
                        quantity[collection.id] = 0;
                        for (const item of collection.items) {
                            if (item.myitems.length) {
                                for (const myitem of item.myitems) {
                                    quantity[collection.id]++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // here's where I'm trying to assign the item count
                        // to a variable so I can bind it to ngModel 
                        // in the view.
                        if (quantity[collection.id] > 0) {
                            collectionId[collection.id] = quantity[collection.id];
                        }
                    }

                }, error => {
                    console.warn(error);
                });
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is this not a legitimate problem and question? Because I've been stuck trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or is the value of quantity[collection.id] not correct?

Comment: @StephenRomero At this point I actually have the quantity working correctly, I just can't figure out how to bind it to each span dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
let collectedCount = items.filter((item) => { return item.myitems.length }).length;
```

Which should:

- filter out your items by only keeping items with a `true` value for `myitems.length` (so items with `>` 0)
- convert the resulting into a number with the last `.length`

### Update

This would replace your big block of code that's not working for you.

You haven't posted all of your code so I don't know what you're already doing but I would get the data back from the service, add on my extra calculated property, and then set the whole result to a public variable that I can iterate over in the ui.

```
storedCollections: any;

getData() {
    return this.storage.get('token').then(res => {
        if (res) {
            this.http.get('http://api.example.com/collections)
                .subscribe((result: any) => {
                    for (const collection of result.data.collections) {
                      let collectedCount = items.filter((item) => { return item.myitems.length }).length;

                      collection.collectedCount = collectedCount;
                    }

                    this.storedCollections = result.data.collections;
                }, error => {
                    console.warn(error);
                });
        }
    });
}
```

I'm just calling it `storedCollections` to be clear that it is different to the `.collections` you are getting back from the api.

And now in the UI you would have this extra `collectedCount` property on your collection data.

(Somewhere further up that you haven't shown, you would loop `storedCollections` - wherever the ngFor is that is making the `collection` of `collection.items.length` you're looping in what you posted).

```
<span class="heading" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="collection.collectedCount"></span> of {{ collection.items.length || '0' }}
```

Comment: Where do I put this? I'm sorry, I come from PHP, so I'm trying to figure this stuff out and it's pretty confusing lol

Comment: ive updated my answer, dont forget to upvote if its helpful :)

Comment: Thank you. My code actually is working, and I'm getting the quantity for each item just fine. My problem is I don't know how to reflect that quantity in the span in the UI, as each item is dynamic. So for now there's 14 items (14 spans), but that can change later, so the IDs can't be hardcoded. if it were 1 item I'd just do `this.quantity = result.data.quantity` and in the span `[(ngModel)]="quantity" but I can't do that with dynamic items, so I can't figure out how to tell which span to accept which quantity in the for loop. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so all I had to do to solve this problem was update the span and use `innerText`.

```
<span class="heading" [innerText]="collection[collection.id]"></span> of {{ collection.items.length || '0' }}
```